# Get min and max datetimes from each subgroup order by starttimes

Tags: sql, sql-server, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, grouping

I basically want to group the set by timeline in SQL, I am so out of ideas right now
obviously group by does not work and so does row number.

Any ideas for SQL are really appreciated.

```
select shift_date,associate_id,name,description , min(START_TRAN_DATE) as startdate, max(end_tran_date) as end_date
from ltu_vt 
group by shift_date,associate_id,name,description
```

```
**SHIFT_DATE    ID  NAME            DESC    START_TRAN_DATE         END_TRAN_DATE**
2022-11-13  42  John Doe    ADP 2022-11-13 06:31:00.000 2022-11-13 06:31:22.000
2022-11-13  42  John Doe    LINE    2022-11-13 06:31:22.000 2022-11-13 06:50:13.000
2022-11-13  42  John Doe    HJ  2022-11-13 06:50:13.000 2022-11-13 06:50:13.000
2022-11-13  42  John Doe    HJ  2022-11-13 06:52:13.000 2022-11-13 06:52:13.000
2022-11-13  42  John Doe    HJ  2022-11-13 06:52:20.000 2022-11-13 06:52:20.000
2022-11-13  42  John Doe    HJ  2022-11-13 06:52:25.000 2022-11-13 06:52:25.000
2022-11-13  42  John Doe    HJ  2022-11-13 06:52:46.000 2022-11-13 06:52:46.000
2022-11-13  42  John Doe    BG  2022-11-13 06:53:58.000 2022-11-13 06:53:58.000
2022-11-13  42  John Doe    BG  2022-11-13 06:54:01.000 2022-11-13 06:54:01.000
2022-11-13  42  John Doe    HJ  2022-11-13 07:13:49.000 2022-11-13 07:13:49.000
2022-11-13  42  John Doe    P2L 2022-11-13 07:14:09.000 2022-11-13 07:14:09.000
2022-11-13  42  John Doe    P2L 2022-11-13 07:19:48.000 2022-11-13 07:19:48.000
2022-11-13  42  John Doe    ADP 2022-11-13 07:20:00.000 2022-11-13 07:20:00.000
```

expected output is

```
**SHIFT_DATE    ID  NAME            DESC   START_TRAN_DATE          END_TRAN_DATE**
2022-11-13  42  John Doe    ADP 2022-11-13 06:31:00.000 2022-11-13 06:31:22.000
2022-11-13  42  John Doe    LINE    2022-11-13 06:31:22.000 2022-11-13 06:50:13.000
2022-11-13  42  John Doe    HJ  2022-11-13 06:50:13.000 2022-11-13 06:52:46.000
2022-11-13  42  John Doe    BG  2022-11-13 06:53:58.000 2022-11-13 06:54:01.000
2022-11-13  42  John Doe    HJ  2022-11-13 07:13:49.000 2022-11-13 07:13:49.000
2022-11-13  42  John Doe    P2L 2022-11-13 07:14:09.000 2022-11-13 07:19:48.000
2022-11-13  42  John Doe    ADP 2022-11-13 07:20:00.000 2022-11-13 07:20:00.000
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Guess what? Snowflake is a totally different product to SQL Server - do yourself a favour and correct your tags so the right experts look at your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

It is a well known "gaps and islands" problem.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (SHIFT_DATE DATE, ID INT, [NAME] VARCHAR(20), [DESC] varchar(10), START_TRAN_DATE datetime, END_TRAN_DATE DATETIME);
INSERT @tbl (SHIFT_DATE, ID, NAME, [DESC], START_TRAN_DATE, END_TRAN_DATE) VALUES
('2022-11-13', 42, 'John Doe', 'ADP', '2022-11-13 06:31:00.000', '2022-11-13 06:31:22.000'),
('2022-11-13', 42, 'John Doe', 'LINE','2022-11-13 06:31:22.000', '2022-11-13 06:50:13.000'),
('2022-11-13', 42, 'John Doe', 'HJ', '2022-11-13 06:50:13.000',  '2022-11-13 06:50:13.000'),
('2022-11-13', 42, 'John Doe', 'HJ', '2022-11-13 06:52:13.000',  '2022-11-13 06:52:13.000'),
('2022-11-13', 42, 'John Doe', 'HJ', '2022-11-13 06:52:20.000',  '2022-11-13 06:52:20.000'),
('2022-11-13', 42, 'John Doe', 'HJ', '2022-11-13 06:52:25.000',  '2022-11-13 06:52:25.000'),
('2022-11-13', 42, 'John Doe', 'HJ', '2022-11-13 06:52:46.000',  '2022-11-13 06:52:46.000'),
('2022-11-13', 42, 'John Doe', 'BG', '2022-11-13 06:53:58.000',  '2022-11-13 06:53:58.000'),
('2022-11-13', 42, 'John Doe', 'BG', '2022-11-13 06:54:01.000',  '2022-11-13 06:54:01.000'),
('2022-11-13', 42, 'John Doe', 'HJ', '2022-11-13 07:13:49.000',  '2022-11-13 07:13:49.000'),
('2022-11-13', 42, 'John Doe', 'P2L', '2022-11-13 07:14:09.000', '2022-11-13 07:14:09.000'),
('2022-11-13', 42, 'John Doe', 'P2L', '2022-11-13 07:19:48.000', '2022-11-13 07:19:48.000'),
('2022-11-13', 42, 'John Doe', 'ADP', '2022-11-13 07:20:00.000', '2022-11-13 07:20:00.000');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT series, SHIFT_DATE, ID, NAME, [DESC], MIN(START_TRAN_DATE) AS Date_Start, MAX(END_TRAN_DATE) AS Date_End, COUNT(SHIFT_DATE) AS Shift_Counter
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
           SUM(IIF([DESC] <> ns, 1, 0)) OVER (ORDER BY START_TRAN_DATE) AS series
    FROM
    (
        SELECT series.*,
               LAG([DESC]) OVER (ORDER BY START_TRAN_DATE) AS ns
        FROM @tbl AS series
    ) q
) q
GROUP BY series, SHIFT_DATE, ID, NAME, [DESC]
ORDER BY series;
```

**Output**

| series | SHIFT_DATE | ID | NAME | DESC | Date_Start | Date_End | Shift_Counter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-11-13 | 42 | John Doe | ADP | 2022-11-13 06:31:00.000 | 2022-11-13 06:31:22.000 | 1 |
| 1 | 2022-11-13 | 42 | John Doe | LINE | 2022-11-13 06:31:22.000 | 2022-11-13 06:50:13.000 | 1 |
| 2 | 2022-11-13 | 42 | John Doe | HJ | 2022-11-13 06:50:13.000 | 2022-11-13 06:52:46.000 | 5 |
| 3 | 2022-11-13 | 42 | John Doe | BG | 2022-11-13 06:53:58.000 | 2022-11-13 06:54:01.000 | 2 |
| 4 | 2022-11-13 | 42 | John Doe | HJ | 2022-11-13 07:13:49.000 | 2022-11-13 07:13:49.000 | 1 |
| 5 | 2022-11-13 | 42 | John Doe | P2L | 2022-11-13 07:14:09.000 | 2022-11-13 07:19:48.000 | 2 |
| 6 | 2022-11-13 | 42 | John Doe | ADP | 2022-11-13 07:20:00.000 | 2022-11-13 07:20:00.000 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

From your expected output it seems that you want to group by `description`, so this is how you could do it:

```
SELECT SHIFT_DATE,
       associate_id ID,
       Name
       description DESC,
       MIN(START_TRAN_DATE),
       MAX(END_TRAN_DATE)
FROM ltu_vt
GROUP BY SHIFT_DATE, ASSOCIATE_ID, DESCRIPTION
```

Note that the only information I have is the info you have given, so, if I misunderstood the problem, provide more information, maybe a SQL fiddle as well.